# Browser window is showing a transparent window rather than the route using Electron Builder

Tags: electron, desktop-application, electron-builder

#### Code used to create the menubar

```js
const createMenubar = () => {
  //our window you can chanege the size  and other

  const devServerURL = createURLRoute("http://localhost:3000", "onboarding");

  const fileRoute = createFileRoute(
    path.join(__dirname, "../", "index.html"),
    "onboarding"
  );

  window = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 550,
    height: 675,
    show: false,
    resizable: false,
    frame: false,
    fullscreenable: false,
    transparent: true,
    minimizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false, // Default is false
      contextIsolation: true, // Default is true
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"), // Use of preload.jsc
      backgroundThrottling: false,
      devTools: true,
    },
  });

  !app.isPackaged
    ? window.loadURL(devServerURL)
    : window.loadFile(...fileRoute);

  createTray();

  window.on("blur", () => {
    window.hide();
  });

  window.on("show", () => {
    // app.on("did-become-active", (event, data) => {
    if (window) window.webContents.send("app-opened", true);
    // });
  });

  window.on("ready-to-show", () => {
    // console.log(process.env);

    toggleWindow();
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.webContents.send("set-user-status", true);
    }, 1000);

    window.webContents.on("before-input-event", (event, input) => {
      console.log(input);

      if (input.meta && input.key.toLowerCase() === "q") {
        event.preventDefault();

        window.webContents.send("set-user-status", false);

        setTimeout(() => {
          app.exit();
        }, 1000);
      }
    });

    if (!app.isPackaged) window.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: "detach" });

    // window.webContents.on('before-input-event', (event, input) => {
    //   if (input.control && input.key.toLowerCase() === 'i') {
    //     console.log('Pressed Control+I')
    //     event.preventDefault()
    //   }
    // })

    //

    // window.webContents.send("alert", "checking for updates");

    
    if (app.isPackaged) {
    }
    // .then((response) => {
    //   window.webContents.send("alert", `updates response: ${response}`);
    // })
    // .catch((err) => {
    //   window.webContents.send("alert", `updates error: ${err}`);
    // });
  });

  // process.on("exit", () => {
  //   window.webContents.send("set-user-status", false);
  // });
};
```

#### Code used to create the onboarding window

```js
const createOnboardingWindow = (data) => {
  if (onboardingWindow) onboardingWindow.close();

  //our window you can chanege the size  and other

  onboardingWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: parseInt(width * 0.7),
    height: parseInt(height * 0.8),
    maxWidth: windowSize.width,
    maxHeight: windowSize.height,
    transparent: true,
    resizable: true,
    frame: false,
    show: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: true, // Default is true
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "preload.js"), // Use of preload.jsc
      backgroundThrottling: false,
    },
  });

  const xSpacing = parseInt((width - windowSize.width) / 2);
  const ySpacing = parseInt((height - windowSize.height) / 2) + 20;

  onboardingWindow.setPosition(xSpacing, ySpacing, false);

  const devServerURL = createURLRoute("http://localhost:3000", "onboarding");

  const fileRoute = createFileRoute(
    path.join(__dirname, "../", "index.html"),
    "onboarding"
  );

  !app.isPackaged
    ? onboardingWindow.loadURL(devServerURL)
    : onboardingWindow.loadFile(...fileRoute);

  // Automatically open Chrome's DevTools in development mode.
  if (!app.isPackaged) {
    onboardingWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  if (process.defaultApp) {
    if (process.argv.length >= 2) {
      app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("meetingReminder", process.execPath, [
        path.resolve(process.argv[1]),
      ]);
    }
  } else {
    app.setAsDefaultProtocolClient("meetingReminder");
  }

  return onboardingWindow;
};
```

Everytime the app is ready, I check if the onboarding is done, and I open the menubar window. The onboarding window works properly with the right route showing.

**But**, the menubar window is not showing the content in the route and it is showing a transparent screen **→** [Take a look at how the menubar is showing now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwpp2.png)

I thought this might be a problem with the route configuration, but in the previous release this was the same configuration, there is not change done to this, but it does not seem to work. This is the route configuration:

```js
menubar={
          <>
            <Route path="/" element={<App />} />
            <Route path="/signin" element={<Signin />} />
            <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
          </>
        }
        onboarding={
          <>
            <Route path="/" element={<Onboarding />} />
            <Route path="/signup" element={<Onboarding />} />
            <Route path="/verifyphone" element={<Onboarding />} />
            <Route path="/welcome" element={<Onboarding />} />
          </>
        }
        notification={
          <>
            <Route path="/" element={<Notify />} />
          </>
        }
        alert={
          <>
            <Route path="/" element={<Alert />} />
          </>
        }
```

**The app works properly with no errors in the development environment**. Could this be any error in the route that it is rendering? There is no error the dev env that is not showing the route in the menubar.

This error is only showing in the production environment, where there the other route like for onbaording is working properly.

**Would really appreciate if anyone could let me know any fixes for this, to get the menubar window to show the route. Thanks.**

Let me know if there is any other code that I need to share.

--

Tried checking if there was any errors with the app route that it is rendering, it is showing errors in the console, but the app in the dev is working properly without showing a transparent screen.

Tried to check if there was any errors with routing but other routes seem to work properly with the same configuration.

It is only showing a transparent screen in the production env.